# Accessing maximum or minimum nested list element

Tags: python, nested, iterable

```
a = [['a', 20], ['b', 36], ['c', 1], ['d', 8], ['e', 55]]
```

How can I print out the minimum value or maximum value by using Python built-in functions like `min()` or `max()`?

The result would look like `['e' , 55]` or `55`.

```
for x in a:
    if x[1].isdigit():
        q = x[1]
    print(q)
print(max(q))
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76827277/edit) your question and format your code - [TUTORIAL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: `max` has an optional `key` argument: `max(a,key = lambda x:x[1])`

Answer (score 0):

If you know that is always at position 1 you can do:

```
>>> a = [['a',20], ['b',36], ['c',1], ['d',8], ['e' , 55]]
>>> min(a, key= lambda sublist: sublist[1])
['c', 1]
```

In short the key function needs to returns a value which "sorts" and then returns the entry at the start/end of this list.
(in the background of course only the current highest/lowest value is kept)